# How to use same service in two angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to google this but I am not getting the answer I am looking for. I have two seperate modules (in seperate html pages - these perform totally unrelated tasks). I have created an authorization service and associated it with module 1 and I am using this $auth service inside my controller via DI. Now I want to use same service in module2. How can I do this?
This is how service looks like :

```
module1.service('$authService', function($http) {
   this.authorise = function(userid,accessKey) {
       // logic for performing auth
   };
});
```

Comment: Make a common module, add the service, and inject the common module into the modules that require this service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a third common module to host your `authService`, and add a dependency to this module in the other two.

```
angular.module("Auth", [])
  .service("authService", function($http){ });
```

And, in another file/module/app:

```
angular.module("module1", ["Auth"])
  .controller("MainCtrl", function(authService){
   });
```

(same with a second module: `angular.module("module2", ["Auth"])`)

Answer (score 1):

While creating second module say module2 provide dependency of module1 into it like

```
angular.module('module2',['module1']);
```

Now you can use service of module1 into module2 same as you were using in module1.

Comment: As I said, my module 1 and module 2 are unrelated. So I am creating a new module (specifically for auth purpose) and will DI them on modules. Nonetheless I will keep your strategy in mind for such needs in future.

Comment: I considered your first module is to just provide the services :-)

Comment: Yup you didn't mentioned it but fine :) You got the solution happy coding :-)